# Android expanding design support FAB

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

How can I show more FABs when clicking on the standard FAB like in many Google apps? I searched on the internet and found no guide on how to achieve this, but I'm sure there is a way. I am using the design support FAB if that matters.

Comment: it is not in the design library,

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is not currently in the design support library. However, there are third party libraries available. For example,
https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Comment: Well I mostly want to do this with the design support library, as I don't want to have to import 2 fab libraries for just one thing

Comment: wrap the fabs in a LinearLayout, with some animations you can achieve the  same thing

Comment: @Blackbelt oh ok I will try that. What kind of animation would that be?

Comment: translate+scale+alpha